# Preserve source ip while sending data out of squid

Tags: squid

I am using a squid proxy to egress to internet .
However, in the process while egressing the source ip of the packet is shown as the squids ip and not the original server's ip which is making the request . I want to change this behavior to present original source's ip .

How can i do it ?

expectation is to have the egress packet have original source ip but it is getting squids ip

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.